# Given the span of S, as S is a plane going through (0, 0, 0). Prove S is the solution space of a cubic equation of the form $ax+by+cz=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

let $$\mathbb{R}^{3}\supseteq S = span_{\mathbb{R}}{\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}\right)} , \left(\begin{array}{c}4\\5\\6\end{array}\right)$$

Is a Plane going through Cartesian coordinate system - $(0, 0, 0)$.

I need to prove that S is the Kernel of equation of the form $$ax + by + cz = 0$$
 for $a, b ,c \in\mathbb{{R}}$ (given the assumption which not all objects = $0$)

i tried to put a, b , c in a matrix of the form: $$\begin{array}{ccc}
a & 2b & 3c\\
4a & 5b & 6c
\end{array}$$

but when i ranked it i could only say what a and b are  in terms of c, which i don't think is the answer. what did i do wrong? (it's defiantly not because of a mistake in the ranking of the  matrix)

Comment: Do you know Cross Product?

Comment: yes, of course. but i'm not sure how to use in order to solve the question.

Comment: you mean i need to take both vectors given, multiply them and compare to 0?

Comment: The entries of the cross product will be the coefficients $a,b,c$

Comment: That’s not a cubic equation.

Comment: Why wouldn’t the answer you got be correct? The equation that you’re looking for isn’t unique: you can multiply it by any nonzero scalar to get a different equation with the same solution set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a plane in our 3 dimensional world, the polynomial equation $ax+by+cz=d$ can be found as follow: Find a normal vector that is normal to both directional vectors, i.e. ${\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}\right)} , \left(\begin{array}{c}4\\5\\6\end{array}\right)$. This can be done with the dot product (that's handy when the problem is expanded into a higher dimension) or the cross product, which works here. Since you indicated that you know how to do cross product, I'll leave it up to you to verify that a normal vector to both directional vectors is $(-3,6,-3)$ and thus the equation of the plane would become $-3x+6y-3z=d$ with $d$ in this case being zero. You may simplify if needed. Verify by substitution that both directional vectors are a solution to the equation (and therefore any linear combination of them will also be a solution)

Comment: Your answer was very much helpful. Unfortunately, at my college they don't teach cross product in the course algebra 1A, but only at the following cousre, linear algebra 2A, therefore I did not know this method. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: You can google "Cross Product" It is very easy. There are applets that will calculate the cross product so you can check yourself while practicing.

Comment: i did! was very helpful